# Meaning of "for the meek"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, american-english, phrase-meaning

I need help with a word in some part of the book  ***Born to Run by Christopher McDougall (Random House, 2018)***

> Hunting like that isn’t for the meek; Neanderthals were known to suffer
>       the kind of injuries you find on the rodeo circuit, neck and head trauma from getting thrown by
>       bucking beasts, but they could count on their band of brothers to care for their wounds and
>       bury their bodies.

The author is talking about the way that Neanderthals haunt, and then he says "Hunting like that isn’t for the meek". I couldn't find out what does he mean by saying 'for the meek". I searched "meek" in dictionaries and read about it but it doesn't help me and since I am translating this book I need a clear understanding of the author's purpose.

Comment: The meek and mild. The meek: those who are quiet and gentle. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/meek

Comment: I wrote that I read that meaning on dictionaries but still, the sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Meek approximates to "timid". The idea is that if you are squeamish about using a rock to smash out the brains of an animal, or are worried by the idea of killing an animal that will fight, then you are not going to be a good hunter.

Comment: 'For' used like this can either mean (illustrating with examples): "Wagner is not for everyone" = "Wagner is not to everyone's taste" OR "Off-gridding is not for everyone" defaults to "Not everyone would cope with / survive a life off grid".  'The meek' means 'those who are meek; compare 'the rich', 'the poor', 'the British'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hunt, you must be brave and forwards or even willing to be bold enough to charge ahead to kill the animals, so if you're too gentle or even too scared, you don't have the courage to do so. That's why the author wrote, "Hunting like that isn't for the meek."

Answer (score 2):

If something is not for the meek, it is not for those people who are meek. We can use an adjective after 'the' to mean those people who have the attribute which the adjective signifies. An often used example is in the phrase 'not for the faint-hearted'. Also 'fortune favours the brave'. Hunting 'like that' (that is, of a kind mentioned immediately before) must have been dangerous, as the following text in your quote makes clear.

> The structure *the + adjective* is used to talk about [...] groups of
>   people. Examples are: the blind, the deaf, the unemployed, the rich,
>   the poor, the young, the old, the dead etc.

[Adjectives used without nouns](https://www.englishgrammar.org/adjectives-nouns/)

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary definition of "meek" is quiet, gentle

The author is implying that the hunting methods of the Neanderthals are not for the faint of heart considering the great risk of injury